# Wireless adapter issues in win10/Ubuntu 16.04 dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, usb, wifi-hardware-switch, d-link

I am still learning ubuntu. Any help is highly appreciated.

I was trying to access 5GHz wifi band and so got a usb wifi adapter - Dlink DWA-171 AC 600

I have tried the following from other questions first which worked for some users:

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux.git
cd rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8812au
```

well, it did not work, so i thought to test it out in windows

this is the ubnutu state before booting into windows

lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:1a2b Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
```

iwconfig:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Dankknight"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.457 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated  
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=55/70  Signal level=-55 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:154  Invalid misc:58   Missed beacon:0

eno1      no wireless extensions.
```

when i switched into windows, the driver got installed automatically and was able to access wifi.
when i boot back into ubuntu,

lsusb :

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2001:331d D-Link Corp.
```

iwconfig then shows :

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlx180f760ace03  unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.457 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

wlo1      IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.457 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Tx-Power=off   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

eno1      no wireless extensions.
```

if i remove the USB and insert it back, the lsusb is getting back to original state.
there are 2 issues i am facing,

1. I am not able to find the right driver installation
2. There is something happening with the windows - firmware? boot options?

I have recently switched to Xfce

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I realize your problem may be already solved by now, but since this question shows up in google as a result, i try to suggest how to solve this to help anyone landing here.

I also have a DWA-171 AC 600 Rev.C1.

What you need to do is to head over to [this repo](https://github.com/uzh-rpg/rpg_dwa171_wifidongle) and follow the readme to install the correct driver (rtl8821cu) which, according to your usb IDs, is the dongle mentioned in [the WikiDevi here](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/D-Link_DWA-171_rev_C1). I suggest the use of DKMS, if your system support it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I can confirm this. *Contrary* to what the [ubuntu wiki says](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsWirelessNetworkCardsDlink#USB), `rtl8812AU` does **not** do the job, however. Thank you! – I should probably edit the wiki, but the process to contribute to the article is ridicously cumbersome, so no thanks